# Displaying FaceBook fan count using Graph API and FQL

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

In my website I am showing some companies' name with their facebook like counts. For most of the companies the counts are coming properly. But for some companies the counts are coming as zero. I have seen that, I even can't open these companies' pages without login to the FB. I think these are secured pages. Can anyone guide me how to get these comapanies' fan/like count? I am using ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to demographically restricted pages. You need an active user `access_token` (that is able to see that page) to retrieve details about the page.

Once you have active access token you can retrieve the fan count by either Graph API request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552?fields=name,likes&access_token=...
```

Or next FQL query:

```
SELECT page_id, name, fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id = 19292868552
```